# How to open the combobox in datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, combobox

I am very new to to silverlight application.I have been trying this for last one day still I am not able to do it. In my case it requires three clicks to open the combobox.

My XAML code:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category" Width="100">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
            <ComboBox Name="cmbCategory"
                IsDropDownOpen="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModel},Mode=OneWay,Path=pcProjTypeTaskCtry}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="TaskCtgyName" SelectedValuePath="TaskCtgy_FK" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding piTaskCtgy_FKField,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding psTaskCtgyNameField,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/> 
        </DataTemplate>

    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SubCategory" Width="110">
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="tbSubCategory" Text="{Binding Path=psTaskSubCtgyNameField,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding psTaskSubCtgyNameField}" >
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModel},Mode=TwoWay,Path=pcTaskSubCtry}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="TaskSubCtgyName" SelectedValuePath="TaskSubCtgyName" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModel},Path=SelectedSubTask,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding psTaskSubCtgyNameField,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding psTaskSubCtgyNameField}"> 
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: You literally have to mousedown (click) 3 times to get the combobox to respond? That's not expected behavior at all, and nothing in your xaml would suggest its intentional. Have you customized the control template at all or anything else that might cause it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Dropdownopened event to the combobox and then assign the datasource to the combobox in the backend.

```
        var obj = (ComboBox)sender;
        obj.ItemsSource = Your list;
        obj.DisplayMemberPath = "pcTaskSubCtry";
```

in the selection changed event you can assign the selected item by casting the selected item as below.

```
 ComboBox cmbbox = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (cmbbox.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            Yourobject obj = new Yourobject() ;
            obj = MainDataGrid.SelectedItem as Yourobje;
            obj.pcTaskSubCtry= Yourobje.pcTaskSubCtry;
        }
```